# Dynamic tasks getting skipped in Airflow DAG

Tags: dynamic, task, airflow

Below is a simple replication of a DAG i have created. The DAG has a branch operator to select an execution flow which merge into a common task. The task is supposed to generate a file list which will be used to create a task for each entry in the list file.
Problem is i am not able to get the dynamic tasks to execute.

```
"""
Required packages to execute DAG
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from builtins import range
import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

import os
import sys


# DAG parameters

args = {
    'owner': 'AD',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 30),
    'end_date': datetime(9999, 12, 31),
    'dagrun_timeout': None,
    'timeout': None,
    'execution_timeout': None,
    'provide_context': True,
}

# create DAG object with Name and default_args (args can set in DAG definition or while execution/runtime)
dag = DAG('sodag', schedule_interval=None, default_args=args)


# Define task - below are examples of tasks created by instantiated by PythonOperator- calling methods written in other py clas
start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)
dummyjoin = DummyOperator(task_id='dummyjoin', dag=dag, trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS)
multidummy = DummyOperator(task_id='multidummy', dag=dag)


def identify_pre_process(**context):
    return 'task1'


def xcl_preq(filename, **kwargs):
    return BashOperator(
            task_id="so_dag{}".format(filename),
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
            provide_context=True,
            bash_command='echo "executing branch tasks"',
            dag=dag)


with dag:
    router = BranchPythonOperator(task_id='trigger_pre_process',
                                  python_callable=identify_pre_process,
                                  dag=dag)

    task1 = BashOperator(
                    task_id="task1",
                    bash_command='echo "executing task1"',
                    execution_timeout=None,
                    dag=dag)

    task2 = BashOperator(
                    task_id="task2",
                    bash_command='echo "executing task2"',
                    execution_timeout=None,
                    dag=dag)

with open('/root/filelist.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for file in fp:
        filename = os.path.basename(file)
        dummyjoin >> xcl_preq(filename) >> multidummy


start >> router
router >> task1 >> dummyjoin
router >> task2 >> dummyjoin
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here what's causing the issue is not the fact that the tasks are generated dynamically, but it's something trickier. Your DAG works very well, except for the following subtle thing: in the line

```
filename = os.path.basename(file)
```

the variable `filename` will contain the newline special character `\n`. In your example, `filename` would take the values `file\n`, `file1\n`, `file2\n`. This causes those tasks to not run since special characters are apparently not allowed as values for task_id (I agree it's weird that no errors is raised at compilation time of the DAG). You don't see through the Graph View of the DAG in the UI, because the newline characters are not rendered there, but if you click on the Details of the DAG, the issue becomes visible.

[image: Dag details screenshot]

A simple fix is to strip out the newline characters from the lines after reading from the file, that is,

```
filename = os.path.basename(file.rstrip())
```

Success!

[image: successful DAG screenshot]